# How to sort emails by date and open the latest email found?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm wondering if there is a way to sort emails by date and then open the latest email found.

I'm trying to search for emails that has a unique tag inside the Body. In order to avoid duplicate emails that have the same tag, I have to sort these emails by date and open the latest email found so that I can reply to it.

Comment: What Outlook version?

Comment: @Maciej Los. It's MS Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to [Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866960(v=office.15).aspx) emails on the [ReceivedTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867228(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns a Date indicating the date and time at which the item was received.

```
 Sub SortByDate() 
  Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
  Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
  Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
  Dim myItems As Outlook.Items 

  Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
  Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
  Set myItems = myFolder.Items 
  myItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"
  For Each myItem In myItems 
   MsgBox myItem.Subject & " ---- " & myItem.ReceivedTime
  Next myItem 
 End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoted! You pointed out a property on which mailitems collection can be sorted/ordered! Cheers, Maciej

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev. The program gets an error on this line:


       myItems.Sort "[RecievedTime]"


It says:

The property "ReceivedTime" is unknown.

Comment: Do you try to sort mail items only? See [Sorting Emails by Received time before processing C# Outlook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308583/sorting-emails-by-received-time-before-processing-c-sharp-outlook) . Also take a look at [Outlook Interop c# sort items not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337839/outlook-interop-c-sharp-sort-items-not-working).

Comment: [RecievedTime] is misspelled.  I corrected it to [ReceivedTime] and it works.

Answer (score 1):

For MS Outlook 2010 and higher use [Items.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866960%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method.

```
Sub SortByDueDate() 
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.TaskItem 
 Dim myItems As Outlook.Items 

 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks) 
 Set myItems = myFolder.Items 
 myItems.Sort "[DueDate]", False 
 For Each myItem In myItems 
 MsgBox myItem.Subject & "-- " & myItem.DueDate 
 Next myItem 
End Sub
```

For previous versions, see this: [Sorting Items in a Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147578%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: The code will not work for MailItems. There is no such property defined.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, the code comes from MSDN, so it it should work. I do believe you have to properly define folder and/or property on which sort have to be done.

Comment: Yes, it comes. But it can be applied to task items, not mail items.