# Outlook not displaying the latest email while automating

Tags: vb.net, outlook, qtp

I am using the following code to retrieve and check an email, but outlook is returning the mail starting from 12/22, which is neither the latest nor the oldest, while on a co worker's machine its picking up the oldest mail.

```
Set oapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oMAPI = oapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oInbox = oMAPI.GetDefaultFolder(6)
oInbox.Display
Set oallmails = oInbox.Items
Set oreqemail = oallmails.GetFirst
For oTotalmail = 1 To oallmails.Count
  ostringmatch = oreqemail.Subject
  'Using regex function to match 
  'If MatchString(ostringmatch,"89554 Completed") Then
  'End If
'Exit For 
Set oreqemail = oallmails.GetNext
Next
```

Am I missing any outlook setting, as the code looks ok to me. 
Thanks

Comment: It works on your coworker's computer, but not yours? I would suspect this first: Set oInbox = oMAPI.GetDefaultFolder(6). It is possible that your folder layouts are different.

Comment: On second thought... Is the mail from 12/22 the oldest mail in that folder?

Answer (score 1):

To be sure that you get always the latest or oldest email in Outlook you need to use the [Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866960.aspx) method of the Items class. It sorts the collection of items by the specified property. The index for the collection is reset to 1 upon completion of this method. The name of the property by which to sort, which may be enclosed in brackets, for example, "[CompanyName]".

Note, **Sort** only affects the order of items in a collection. It does not affect the order of items in an explorer view.

```
 Set oapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set oMAPI = oapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set oInbox = oMAPI.GetDefaultFolder(6)
 oInbox.Display
 Set oallmails = oInbox.Items
 oallmails.Sort "[RecievedTime]"
 Set oreqemail = oallmails.GetFirst
 For oTotalmail = 1 To oallmails.Count
  ostringmatch = oreqemail.Subject
  'Using regex function to match 
  'If MatchString(ostringmatch,"89554 Completed") Then
  'End If
  'Exit For 
  Set oreqemail = oallmails.GetNext
 Next
```

See [Outlook VBA: How to sort emails by date and open the latest email found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443783/outlook-vba-how-to-sort-emails-by-date-and-open-the-latest-email-found) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I think the sort method is not built for outlook in QTP (the tool I am using). During run time its saying invalid property. I tried lots of combination -DueDtae,UnRead etc, but it did not worked. Anyhow I modified the code and now its getting me the latest email and looping correctly.----    line 7 -    Set oreqemail = oallmails.GetLast , Line 2nd last - Set oreqemail = oallmails.GetPrevious