# Get the date of the oldest mail per category

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-filter

I have a macro to get the count of mails category-wise in Outlook.

Along with that I want the oldest mail date in a particular category. e.g. in the Red category there are 20 mails, so what is the date of the oldest mail in the Red category?

```
Sub CategoriesEmails()

Dim oFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim oDict As Object
Dim sStartDate As String
Dim sEndDate As String
Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
Dim sStr As String
Dim sMsg As String
Dim strFldr As String
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim xlApp As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set oFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

sStartDate = Date - 365
sEndDate = Date
Set oItems = oFolder.Items.Restrict("[Received] >= '" & sStartDate & "' And [Received] <= '" & sEndDate & "'")
oItems.SetColumns ("Categories")

For Each aItem In oItems
sStr = aItem.Categories
If Not oDict.Exists(sStr) Then
oDict(sStr) = 0
End If
oDict(sStr) = CLng(oDict(sStr)) + 1
Next aItem

sMsg = ""
i = 0

strFldr = "C:\Users\singhab\Desktop\Macro\"
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Application.Visible = True
xlApp.Workbooks.Open strFldr & "Test.xlsx"
xlApp.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
For Each aKey In oDict.Keys
xlApp.Range("a1").Offset(i, 0).Value = sMsg & aKey
xlApp.Range("B1").Offset(i, 0).Value = oDict(aKey) & vbCrLf
i = i + 1
Next
xlApp.Save

Set oFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

I get the output
[image: Result after running the above macro]

What I want is
[image: oldest mail date for each particular category]

Comment: today()  is not enable. Cange to date

Comment: Try implementing a restrict https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict based on aKey which is Category then sort by date. Example sort the opposite way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443783/how-to-sort-emails-by-date-and-open-the-latest-email-found

Answer (score 0):

*Work with [Items.GetFirst Method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.GetFirst) which Returns An Object value that represents the first object contained by the collection*

*Code Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict("[Categories] = 'Red Category'")

    Dim Item As Object
    Set Item = Items.GetFirst

    Debug.Print Item.Subject & " " & Item.ReceivedTime
End Sub
```