# How to extract only the latest or today attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to extract only the latest or today attachment.

I can only get one attachment and it is always the first (oldest) email.

```vb
Sub Download_Attachments()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("nflow")
    
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim fo As Outlook.Folder
    Dim at As Outlook.Attachment
    
    Set fo = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("XXXXX").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Ad Hoc").Folders("XXXX")
    'Set fo = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("XXXX@XXXX.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("test")
    
    'Filter folder
    '    Set oOlInbFiltered = fo.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True AND [Subject] = 'TEST SUBJECT' AND [ReceivedTime]>='" & Format(Date, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'")
    
    Dim lr As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    
    count = 0
    
    For Each msg In fo.Items
        lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
    
        sh.Range("A" & lr + 1).Value = msg.Subject
        sh.Range("B" & lr + 1).Value = msg.Attachments.count

        If count = 0 Then
            For Each at In msg.Attachments
                If VBA.InStr(at.Filename, ".xlsx") > 0 Then
                    at.SaveAsFile sh.Range("G1").Value & "\" & at.Filename
                End If
            Next
        'count = count + 1
        End If
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort emails by date and open the latest email found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443783/how-to-sort-emails-by-date-and-open-the-latest-email-found)

Answer (score 0):

Use the (commented out) line of your code that calls `Restrict()`. You can also call `oOlInbFiltered.Sort` to sort on the received time.